# PowerShell - Select-Object expression not accepting Variable

Tags: powershell

Im new to powershell and im trying to make a small script to check port numbers in my company computers.

```
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\servers.txt")) {
Invoke-Command -HideComputername $line -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue { Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Termin*Server\WinStations\RDP*CP\ | Select-Object @{n='Hostname';e={$line}}, PortNumber}}
```

OutPut

```
Hostname   : 
PortNumber : 3389
RunspaceId : a6739f5a-c9ea-46a4-b9c0-ced6a49bd4f8
```

I wonder why the Hostname is not showing and why the output show the "RunspaceID" value.

Comment: Using `@{n='Hostname';e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}` should do it. Don't forget `invoke-command` also has `-argumentlist` you can pass in parameter values. Sometimes you might have to append `$using:` to your variable names set in the `-Scriptblock` for it to use the variables set out the `-scriptblock` so  `@{n='Hostname';e={$using:line}}` for example. If you pass in the value(s) with `-argumentlist`, it works well too. So are some quick thoughts and things for you to play with and read up on more if you have time. Keep having fun playing with PowerShell!! I'm having a blast with it!!

Comment: Yea, that was what i was missing - e={$using:line}} -. Its working now, i also learned theres many other ways to pass the Hostname but its good to know how to pass a variable aswell. Thanks alot and yeah im having alot of fun aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the
[Invoke-Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2)
with the following parameter:

> -HideComputerName
>
> Indicates that this cmdlet omits the computer name of each object from
> the output display. By default, the name of the computer that
> generated the object appears in the display.

This is probably the reason that the computer name is missing in the output.

Comment: harrymc you are rigt, the -HideComputerName is hiding the PSComputerName from the Select-Object results, althou the $line is a variable from the server.txt file. If i remove the -HideCOmputerName the variable is still empty. Anyways thanks for the help (how did i miss it), it does the job.

Edit: The RunspaceID still showing somehow.